# What to use instead of BufferedReader for server

Tags: java, serversocket, java-server

I was told that `BufferedReader.readLine()` is not a suitable method to read data from clientSocket, because it consideres a line as a String ending with `\n` or `\r`. However, my ending symbol for line is `\r\n`. What should I use insted of buffered reader?

Comment: BufferedReader is just fine. Just reading the javadoc would tell: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine(): "A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), **or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed**.

Comment: Yes, but if I get a line with `\r` or `\n` inside, BufferedReader will return me shorter line than I expected, right?

Comment: If you are dealing with text, `\r` or `\n` means a new line. If you are not dealing with text, you should treat the data as bytes, forget the concept of "line" and use an `InputStream`.

Comment: Ok, that will be probably better option. Please, answer the question so I can accept it

Comment: Correct, but I agree 100% with SJuan76. Don't use a BufferedReader if you're not dealing with text. Text doesn't contain "lines" with a \r or a \n in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was told that BufferedReader.readLine() is not a suitable method to read data from clientSocket, because it consideres a line as a String ending with `\n` or `\r`.

You were told wrong. See the Javadoc.

> However, my ending symbol for line is \r\n. What should I use insted of buffered reader?

You don't need anything instead of `BufferedReader`. It will recognize that as a line terminator. See the Javadoc.

> ... if I get a line with `\r` or `\n` inside

There is no such thing.

Comment: Actually, there is such as thing. I call it line, but it is a message that can contain \r or \n and all I know is that it ends with \r\n

Comment: There is only such a thing if you personally redefine what you personally mean by a line, as you have done. Out here in the real world, the concept of a line that contains line terminators is meaningless.